# Change ad cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, ads

I want to be able to add cookies so that the "smart ads" or ads that track your search history read off of my cookies, if that makes sense. I.e, I put Apple-related cookies in, and I start seeing apple ads. I have no clue how to approach this. **Can someone explain how tracker ads work and how to feed them data *with code*?** Let me know if this needs clarification.
John

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. You don't magically get ads on your site by creating cookies.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  You know when websites show ads targeted towards recent searches you've done? I want to be able to control which ads are shown by changing the cookies that determine those ads

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Those data are stored on their servers and the cookies are merely a way to identify you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to create cookies that will affect the ads from other servers. The searches that you do on other servers will be saved on their servers.